# How to export biblatex data to HTML?

Tags: biblatex, html

I've been using `biblatex` for a while, and I now want to export my `biblatex`
citation data to HTML, too.

There are `bibtex2html` and some other tools for `bibtex`, but I couldn't find
any equivalent tool to do the same for `biblatex`.

Is there any tool to do like what "`bibtex2html`" do for `bibtex` files?

Comment: [Pandoc](http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html) can use `.bib` databases and [csl styles](http://citationstyles.org) to produce html files

Comment: Jabref can export .bib files to four types of HTML.

Comment: What do you want? If you need a pretty bibliography, create a small file using \nocite{*} to add all entries in *.bib files to the bibliography.

Comment: I think we need a bit more detail of what is required here: possibly the comments answer, possibly something else is needed. For example, one could write a `biblatex` driver to produce HTML or XML, but would need to know what was required.

Comment: @JosephWright What? It's pretty clear that OP is looking for a tool analogous to "bibtex2html" but that works with biblatex databases. What exactly is unclear about this?